# Prevent form from reload in laravel modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am working on modal submit form , the problem that when I click on submit in the modal, the whole page is reloaded and all the other data is cleared.

I have tried a lot of solutions but none has worked.
For example adding return false

This is the blade file

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg col-md-3 btn-primary">..{{ __('adminstaticword.Submit') }}</button>
</div>
```

post function in the Controller

```
return back()->with('success',trans('flash.AddedSuccessfully'));
```

In file web.php

```
Route::post('admin/class/{id}/addsubtitle','SubtitleController@post')->name('add.subtitle');
```

Comment: You should make the submission of the model with JS function and make the modal submit button type -"button" not "submit"

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan  I have done that but it doesn't work

Comment: Please show me your try. Update the question with your try.

Comment: have you tried to submit from data ajax ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the old() method in input field value attribute just like it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).